# Macbook Pro OSX El Capitan 10.11.3 and Technicolor TC8717T Router

Tags: macbook-pro, router

The Wifi disconnects every few minutes and only comes back online if Wifi is toggled off and on from the laptop. This only happens with this router. And the MB Pro is the only device in the home that has this issue.

I've already set a static location in Wifi settings (not automatic mode). I've read dozens of posts of similar sounding issues and tried every step they suggested. I'm starting to feel like there is a bug somewhere in either Apple's software or the Router's firmware. This has been happening for months now.

Comment: Bump. I'm having this exact problem with this exact router. I'm on Yosemite 10.10.5. I'm currently trying the static location to see if that helps.

Comment: I have the same issue... Please let me know once you find an answer